# No X509V3CertificateGenerator javadoc in bouncycastle

Tags: java, jar, javadoc, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am trying to use X509V3CertificateGenerator for certification generation, however, Netbeans gives an error and says that Javadoc of that class is not attached to bouncycastle.

I have downloaded bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar into the project's libraries.

How can I download a javadoc?

Thanks.

Comment: try: https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

Comment: @Jens I've downloaded  the file under Provider column (JDK 1.5 - JDK 1.8 version) from that page. Which one should I download?

Answer (score 0):

X509V3CertificateGenerator is deprecated. Use X509v3CertificateBuilder instead. 
You'll find it's Javadoc in bcpkix-jdk15on-152.zip or bcpkix-jdk15on-152.tar.gz
The x509V3 generator/builder isn't/wasn't in the provider jar.
It's in the PKIX/CMS/EAC/PKCS/OCSP/TSP/OPENSSL jar.(https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar)

Here is the online Javadoc:
https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509v3CertificateBuilder.html

To download the Javadoc/sources, pick whichever you prefer:

- https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-152.zip
- https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-152.tar.gz